# Adobe (Harman) 50.2 Air SDK Can not Include JavaScript files

Tags: sdk, harman

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0"> 
    <id>examples.html.HelloWorld</id> 
    <versionNumber>0.1</versionNumber> 
    <filename>HelloWorld</filename> 
    <initialWindow> 
        <content>main.html</content> 
        <visible>true</visible> 
        <width>400</width> 
        <height>200</height> 
    </initialWindow> 
</application>
```

in **main.html** I use following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
```

So run this this command.

```
adl.exe d:\Projects\air\app.xml
```

Modal window opened but test.js script not working anymore. If write

```
<script>
alert('Test');
</script>
```

it works. But included by  not.